# Do pdfTeX, XeTeX and LuaTeX share any code with Knuth's original TeX?

Tags: xetex, pdftex, luatex

The title contains the entire question. The engines are different, but do they still share some code with Knuth's TeX, or are they "remakes" from scratch?

Comment: You'll need to define 'share' here: LuaTeX has been written starting from pdfTeX, written starting from TeX90, but translated to C and altered so you won't find the same lines.

Comment: To anyone who wants to protest against the word "remake:" There was a reason I put it in quotation marks.

Comment: @JosephWright, that actually answers a lot of my questions.

Comment: Putting it in quotes doesn't define it though, you really need to define "share", "code" and "scratch" before it can be answered.

Comment: What 'original TeX' refers to needs to be clarified as well. The first TeX was written in [SAIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAIL_%28programming_language%29) to run on a [PDP-10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-10) under the [WAITS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAITS) OS.

Comment: As the comments suggest, at present this is really not answerable!